# Calling a Function that is part of a union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In this [code sample](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/63e173c806bdfc879d13a0069debb73f4a757bf6/src/validation/ValidationUtils.ts#L10):

```
static replaceMessageSpecialTokens(message: string|((args: ValidationArguments) => string),
                            validationArguments: ValidationArguments): string {

    let messageString: string;
    if (message instanceof Function) {
        messageString = (message as (args: ValidationArguments) => string)(validationArguments);
```

The author calls the function (When it is a function) like this:

```
 messageString = (message as (args: ValidationArguments) => string)(validationArguments);
```

Curious why not:

```
      messageString = message(validationArguments);
```

Does Typescript bark at the lack of typing in this case?  We have a type guard `Function` in place we know what the function signature will be then, so the additional type specification feels redundant ...

Comment: Yeah I would assume so, but it seems feels odd to require all the typing again, given that we specified it in the function argument list ..

Comment: Current version of TypeScript (2.9) will not complain if you leave off the typing, since it understands that `(message instanceof Function)` being true acts as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) which will narrow `message` from the union to just a single function type.  Maybe back when that code was written it wasn't the case?  Or maybe the author was just being extra cautious?

Comment: Whoops, I somehow missed the type guard. My bad.